# I am trying to writer a simple MA Cross Strategy using PineScript and I get this function error message. I believe I have everything named correctly

Tags: pine-script

I am attempting to test a simple MA Cross Strategy and I get stuck here and not sure if it will compile even if this error is corrected.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Instead, copy and paste it here and use the code formatting blocks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have defined `ma1Method = ema` but `ema` is not defined anywhere.

Also, you are using `ma1Method` as if it was a function with the following statement.

```
fastMA = Ma1Method(close, ma1Length)
```

However, it is not a function, it is a variable. This is why you are getting that error message.

Additionally, you don't have any pine version (`//@version`) declarations so the compiler will assume it is v1. And `ema` is actually a built-in function name in that version. If you want to use that function, you should be passing a source and length (e.g. `ma1Method = ema(close, 50)`).